# What cell is this? 1865 or 18650?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion

I am trying to replace rechargeable lithium-ion cells in a Black and Decker hand vacuum and confused with what type of cell it is. It says "LGDAHD11865" on the battery.

Here is the image of the battery:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZucV.jpg

If someone can provide, link to the amazon (U.S.) that would be even awesome :)

**EDIT**: Diameter ~ 1.6cm and Length ~ 6.3cm

Comment: If the battery in the photo is the one you have in your hand, just measure its diameter and length. 18650 is a physical cell size.

Comment: maybe: https://akkuplus.de/LG-LGDAHA11865-ICR18650HA1-36-Volt-1300mAh-Li-Ion-LiNiMnCoO

Comment: @DKNguyen Added measurements in the post.

Comment: @Mike That look likes the same one but I can't seem to find here in U.S. with google.

Comment: Seems like it is 18mm x 65mm. Only you know how accurate your measurements really are (are you using calipers? And don't short the cell out if you are using metal calipers). If it's a 18650 lithium ion then any 18650 lithium ion should do (not lithium something else).

Comment: https://s.alicdn.com/@sc04/kf/HTB1G92qe9SD3KVjSZFKq6z10VXaM.jpg

Answer (score 1):

It's a 18560 Li-ion cell. (Not "lithium", not "battery".) You can replace it with just about any 18650 Li-ion cell.